# Carriage return not detected in python in some cases

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, carriage-return

In the code below I am getting characters from serial input and when a carriage return is detected it will save the value and overwrite the line variable. The issue is that when an error is triggered 2 lines sometimes are added together as if no carriage return is present.

The serial output seems fine with carriage return present where expected.

```
line = ""
        while True:
            data = self.ser.read()
            if(data == "\r"):
                print line
                if line == "check probe":
                    print "CHECK PROBE IF TRIGGERED."
                else:
                    # save line value to a different variable here.
                    print "VALID VALUE ELSE TRIGGERED."
                    line = ""
            else:
                line += data
```

Output snippet when there is an issue with the sensor:

```
CHECK PROBE IF TRIGGERED.
check probecheck probe
VALID VALUE ELSE TRIGGERED.
check probe
CHECK PROBE IF TRIGGERED.
check probe7.00
VALID VALUE ELSE TRIGGERED.
7.20
```

As you can see the lines run together. What is causing this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `line = ""` in the `if` case.

```
if line == "check probe":
    print "CHECK PROBE IF TRIGGERED."
    line = ""
```